# Problems installing JMeter

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, batch-file, jmeter

I just downloaded the latest version of JMeter from http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi , and unzipped the files. I tried jmeter from bat and then got an error saying that the JAR file was missing. Then I copied the JAR file in the bin directory and I get the following error : -

```
C:\workspace\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin>jmeter.bat
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\workspace\apache-jmeter-2.11\lib\ext
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:99)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\workspace\apache-jmeter-2.11\lib\junit
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:99)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:214)
JMeter home directory was detected as: C:\workspace\apache-jmeter-2.11
```

I am not sure what I need to do now.

Thanks,

Comment: what did you download, source or binary?, If binary then all paths are relative and no need to configure anything. unzip binary file and bat or sh file should run as it is. Source is for development and doesn't include any jar by default you need to download all the jars and put them in lib directory and not bin and then build (not install)the jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried jmeter from bat and then got an error saying that the JAR file was missing.

It's quite strange. Try to re-download from here:

- https://www.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.13.zip